# Google Cloud (gcloud) - Client VPN

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vpn

Environment: Google Cloud w/ GSuite
Requirement: Users on Windows/Linux/Android/iOS need to be able to VPN into VPC of a Google Project.  Ideally integrate with the user accounts in GSuite (Cloud Identity)

GCloud:
"Cloud VPN only supports site-to-site IPsec VPN connectivity, subject to the requirements listed in this section. It does not support client-to-gateway (road warrior) scenarios. In other words, Cloud VPN doesn't support use cases where client computers need to "dial in" to a VPN using client VPN software."

https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/overview#vpn-types

Therefore Cloud VPN does NOT appear to be a valid option.

Other Hyperscalers appear to address this need, but not Google.

Azure: https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/aad.azurevpnclient
AWS: https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/client-vpn-download/

Comment: So how about installing a different VPN software (non-Googlish) on a dedicated GCE instance inside your VPC? Recommendations about choosing the exact solution are out of scope of this site, this is why I am posting this as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Google Market Place seems to push OpenVPN Access.  You need an OpenVPN subscription and GSuite Business Plus subscription to integrate via LDAP (if you don't want to manage a local user database as well).  It seems cumbersome compared to the other hyperscalers.  I just wanted to ensure there wasn't a more elegant solution from Google.

Comment: What do you want to connect to? Perhaps the IAP (Identity-Aware-Proxy) is something that you can use?
This works for http(s) and ssh.
For ssh: maybe use reverse tunnels?

Comment: Correct, Cloud VPN allows you to connect on-premise networks to your VPC.  
In order to create a VPN gateway for client (that supports G Suite), you can use  
a third-party solution, for example [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/configuring-google-secure-ldap-with-openvpn-access-server/).  
If you think this is an option that should be implemented, feel free to follow this documentation:  
[Report issues and request features with issue trackers](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) and submit a **Feature Request**.